# Rendering a filled form in the template

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play! framework 20 on a java project and I have a problem with passing a form to the view.

In the controller I have the following code:

```
Filter filter = new Filter();
//add some state to the filter object
Form<Filter> filterForm = form(Filter.class).fill(filter);
Logger.info("FilterForm: " + filterForm.get().toString()); // So far so good
return ok(filterView.render(filterForm));
```

And in the template:

```
@filterForm.hasErrors() // renders false
@filterForm.data().isEmpty() // renders true!!
@*  @filterForm.get().toString()  *@ throws an Exception: No Value
```

I also get the same error if in the controller I fill the filter state via a Map:

```
filterForm = filterForm.bind(aMapWithTheState);
```

This behaviour is only when filling the filter in code. when I do `filterForm.bindFromRequest()` in other methods all works fine.

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe provide more of your code?

I mean, if you use fill() then hasErrors() will return false because no validation has taken place yet and data() will be empty because that's a Map and it never got filled in. However, get() should return your Filter object so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had to use the form's `bind` method using a map with the state as I did before. But the correct way is to also pass the properties name:

```
Map<String, String> formState = new HashMap<String, String>();
formState.put("name", name);
formState.put("birthDate", birthDate);
formState.put("address", address);

filterForm = filterForm.bind(formState, "name", "birthDate", "address");
```

Despite that the [documentation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaForms) says that the property names are not mandatory.